# Drivers not installing on windows 7 ultimate x64

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, 64-bit

Im facing the ever-ending driver problem in windows.
I have a feature phone with microSD card inserted. The phone has a microUSB port. When I connect to my "PC" notification pops up

`Installing device driver..`

When i click on it, the detailed status message shows

```
>>Searching Windows Update

>>Searching pre-configured drivers folder

>>No driver found
```

On `Device Manager` **Generic Disk1.0** and **Remote USB Bus** properties shows

***The drivers for this device are not installed.***

I tried uninstalling then updating the drivers again but no avail.

And this is not the only case, there are several problems I found on installing drivers automatically when device(GSM Modem/ Android Devices) connected to usb (2.0) ports.

Im facing these problems on a regular basis recently ( the past month ).

My guess is, I think i need to make some change on `REGISTRY`, but dont know where exactly should change.

Is there any way to complete uninstall ( REGKEY Removed ) of some specific drivers?

Comment: Have you got any [restore points](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/system-restore-faq#1TC=windows-7)?

Comment: @and31415 No, on windows forum i found the solution is to reinstall windows :@.

Comment: Does this happen only when installing USB devices?

Comment: @and31415 Yeap. Other internal drivers are working fine. Even previously installed USB drivers are ok.

Comment: Try running this Microsoft troubleshooting tool and report back: http://support.microsoft.com/mats/hardware_device_problems